# What's wrong with the expression `new ListBuffer.empty[Int]`

Tags: scala, collections

I found this works well:

```
val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]
```

But, this doesn't work:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val buf = new ListBuffer.empty[Int]
```

The compiler complains:

```
Error:(2, 32) type empty is not a member of object scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
lazy val buf = new ListBuffer.empty[Int]
                              ^
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListBuffer.empty` isn't a constructor, it's just a function that returns an empty ListBuffer.

There's no need for the `new` keyword.